# xtext maven build fails under Jenkins/docker

Tags: eclipse, maven, docker, jenkins, xtext

I'm working on an xtext DSL project using xtext2.13/java8. It all builds and executes regression tests under maven, and now I want to move the build to run under CI with Jenkins. The Jenkins job runs maven in a docker image. I'm specifically using the docker image "maven:3.5-jdk-8". 
I can see that the build starts -- log shows p2 dependencies being downloaded, but it then fails with this exception:

```
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/eclipse/tycho/org.eclipse.tycho.p2.tools.impl/1.0.0/org.eclipse.tycho.p2.tools.impl-1.0.0.jar (48 kB at 630 kB/s)
[WARNING] Error initializing: org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2DependencyResolver@72725ee1
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Service is not registered class='interface org.eclipse.tycho.core.shared.ProxyServiceFacade'
at org.eclipse.sisu.equinox.embedder.internal.DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.checkStarted (DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.java:312)
...
```

I can run the docker/maven build in a local docker and it works fine. I'm only seeing this error when I run it in a Jenkins pipeline.

The error doesn't give any kind of clue as to what the underlying problem might be. I can only guess that it is likely to be one of the following:

- different access to external repos (but it was able to download dozens of other resources before this)
- different local permissions (maybe missing permission to some resource?)

Any other suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: I should add that this WARNING turns into a MUCH longer stack trace that turns into a maven error, and whose most deeply nested exception is: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Service is not registered class='interface org.eclipse.tycho.core.shared.ProxyServiceFacade' and the build fails. Have not been able to reproduce this in local maven build, or running local instance of same container in docker (though I may be invoking docker differently, or it may be a different version of docker)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem. Posting my solution for reference.

The root cause was that Maven local repository directory contained a `?` in the path (i.e. `?/.m2/repository`) and Tycho couldn't resolve the directory properly (regular Maven dependencies were fine).
This happens because if you use the `--user` flag when running the container and inside the container there is no mapping for that user in `/etc/passwd` the `${user.home}` is not properly resolved.

The solution was to specify the path manually to a valid path in the `mvn` command, e.g.
`-Dmaven.repo.local=/path/to/repo`

I guess other options are to:

- specify the path in Maven settings file, or
- to have the corresponding user available in the container (e.g. add the addtional argument to the container `-v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro`)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you please report it as a bug to Tycho or Maven? The error message could at least be improved.

Comment: Bug report: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=552877